# Ugly url in mvc3-how make it nice looking?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, url, maproute

Have an action in `Ideas` controller in my aplication:

```
public ViewResult NewIdeas(int numberOfPage = 1)
```

that action "produces" url like that:

```
/Ideas/NewIdeas/?numberOfPage=1
```

it's quite ugly-it should be just:

```
/Ideas/NewIdeas/1
```

I know that new MapRoute propably will solve problem-but how it should look like?
Thanks for help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should add a new route in global.asax:

```
  routes.MapRoute(
      "NewIdeas", // Route name
      "Ideas/NewIdeas/{numberOfPage}", // URL with parameters
      new { controller = "Ideas", action = "NewIdeas", numberOfPage= UrlParameter.Optional } // Parameter defaults
  );
```